# keeping laravel session variable till user logs out

Tags: session, laravel-4, session-variables

I have a simple authentications for user,In UserController I have a fuction called postLogin().

```
public function postLogin()
{
 if(Auth::user()->attempt($credentials))
  {
  return Redirect::intended('desk')->with('stream',"SomeData");;
  }
}
```

with above code I am able to log in successfullt with the "SomeData" variable which I am retrieving it by

```
 <?php
 $class = Session::get('stream');
 var_dump($class);
 ?>
```

First time when it goes to "/desk" url it dumps the value perfectly fine that is "SomeData" but once I refresh the page it resets the session and the value turns to null.

How do I keep this value till the user logs out.

Comment: If you have kept the value in session then it must shows those value till session is no destroyed.

Comment: So m i not storing the value in session properly according to code?

Comment: where you have set the value for `stream` in session ? I cannot see in your code . To set  data in session `Session::set('stream','somedata');`  in your controller .

Comment: i am just passing a variable with redirecting route,how can we pass set the session variable with redirecting on login

Comment: check the answer below .

Comment: Can you show your logout function?

Comment: I have added a new quesion with some detailed description for the same, can please look at this link 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239771/laravel-multi-aiuth-with-multiple-table-session-set-till-user-logout'

Answer (score 0):

From the laravel official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) :

**Flash Data**

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next
>   request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the
>   session using this method will only be available during the subsequent
>   HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful
>   for short-lived status messages:

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

> If you need to keep your flash data around for even more requests, you
>   may use the `reflash` method, which will keep all of the flash data
>   around for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific
>   flash data around, you may use the `keep` method:

```
$request->session()->reflash();

$request->session()->keep(['username', 'email']);
```

Comment: Is there anything like Session::put("key","value") with redirecting? Because after login I am getting the "SomeData" but it dissapears when I refresh the page.

Comment: did you try my answer ??

Comment: Yes I tried the with redirecting but it says Class session cannot be used with redirect.

Comment: To be more clear,I using multi auth with multiple tables suppose with table users,table students1 and table students2, Login process is perfectly fine for all the tables even filters are working good,But after login to students1,I dyanamically set the auth check with value geting from student login page.and the same value I want to keep in session for the logout process. but the value comes only once after login,as I refresh I resets the values and turns to null.

Comment: I am not sure but flash also resets after refreshing the page.

Comment: you cannot use flash data for more then one request mate .See in the answer **Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted**. So, if you want to set the session variable then you should use `Session::set('your_varible','your_value')` .